# How can I change the default phpMyAdmin access URL for AWS EC2 running Linux AMI

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, ec2-ami

I just installed MySQL and phpMyAdmin on my AWS EC2 instance running Linux AMI. I would like to find out how to change the default URL to access phpMyAdmin, which is currently /phpMyAdmin. I found an article on how to do this:
     https://www.tecmint.com/change-secure-phpmyadmin-login-url-page/ 
but there is no such file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf. The only config file I can find is the sample config file: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin/config.sample.inc.php. But this sample config file doesn't seem to have anything about url alias.

Would appreciate some help on this, thanks!